# Hashmap in Hashmap Search

Tags: java, hashmap

```
Map<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, 

HashMap<String, Integer>>();
map.put(1, new HashMap<>());
map.get(1).put("123",5);
map.get(1).put("124",3);
// i store (id, isbn, rate) in Hashmap in Hashmap

map.put(2, new HashMap<>());
map.get(2).put("123",5);
map.get(2).put("122",2);
```

How i get id from isbn?

Example i want to get id of the users who read isbn 123?
    Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to think by steps :

- Iterate over the pairs of the first level Map
- for each one, iterate over its pair (second level Map)
- if you find a pair with the good `isbn` then save the ID of the 1-lvl Map

You can build a method as follows, and call like this

```
List<Integer> listId = getIdFromIsbn("123", map);
```

```
static List<Integer> getIdFromIsbn(String isbn, Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> map) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Map<String, Integer> value = entry.getValue();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> subEntry : value.entrySet()) {
            if (subEntry.getKey().equals(isbn)) {
                list.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

---

Using `Stream` and lambdas, it would look like :

```
static List<Integer> getIdFromIsbn(String isbn, Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> map) {
    return map.entrySet()                           // Set<Entry<Integer,Map<String,Integer>>>
            .stream()                               // Stream<Entry<Integer,Map<String,Integer>>>
            .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet() // Set<Entry<String,Integer>>
                    .stream()                             // Stream<Entry<String,Integer>>
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)               // Stream<String> 
                    .filter(isbn::equals)                 // Stream<String> 
                    .map(subEntry -> entry.getKey()))     // Stream<Integer>
            .collect(Collectors.toList());                // List<Integer>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the maps directly:

```
List<Integer> idsFound = new ArrayList<>(); 
map.forEach((id, innerMap) -> innerMap.forEach((isbn, rate) -> {
    if (isbn.equals(isbnToMatch)) idsFound.add(id);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the first level map, then iterate over the nested map to perform your check.

Following code section prints all the `id` for a given `targetIsbn`

```
    for (Entry<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        int id = entry.getKey();
        Map<String, Integer> value = entry.getValue();

        for (Entry<String, Integer> subEntry : value.entrySet()) {
            String isbn = subEntry.getKey();
            int rate = subEntry.getValue();
            if (isbn.equals(targetIsbn))
                System.out.println("given isbn found for id " + id);
        }
    }
```